# Power series of two variables [Mary L. Boas, Mathematical Methods in the Physical Science]

Tags: multivariable-calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

In Mathematical Methods in the Physical Science by Mary L. Boas, the general formula for power series of two variables is (2.7):

$$f(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(h\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + k \frac{\partial}{\partial y})^n f(a,b)$$
What are constants h and k in this formula?

Answer (score 1):

They should be $x-a$ and $y-b$ respectively.